# Why can not I use fcitx input method in gnome-terminal?

Tags: archlinux

After reinstalling my archlinux, I can't use fcitx input method in gnome-terminal. But it's ok in other programs such as gedit, fcitx-configtool. When in terminal, ctrl + space makes no effect. Why? What could have happened during my re-installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I have resolved the question. I put "LC_ALL=zh_CN.UTF-8" in my ~/.xinitrc so that gnome-session can not find correct config-file somewhere. Then it set XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus for me, which is not expected. After removing LC_ALL assignment, I can type Chinese in gnome-terminal again!

But, thank you too. And you can ignore this question.